# Programming Environment that runs directly on the iPhone or iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, development-environment

Is there a development environment that runs directly on an the iPhone OS?

I will be without access to a computer/internet for some time, but will have the use of an iPad (WiFi, jailbroken). Do you know of any way to dabble with programming directly on the device.

Since apple is commit to not let it happen, I assume I will have to find such an environment on cydia (or a 'similar' site). I don't seem to be able to find the correct google incantations (search terms) to locate such a package.

---

STATUS UPDATE: 2010.05.07:

- The gcc (c-programming) packages on [CYDIA](http://cydia.saurik.com/) don't install (missing library *libgcc*)
- Mobile Terminal, needed for the workaround, doesn't work yet on the iPAD
- Classpath (Java) doesn't work (won't start)

**CONCLUSION** The only option remaining is to ssh into the iPad from another machine, that is reported to wrk though I didn't even try, since I won't have that other machine with me.

---

Comment: From a quick look in the Rock/Cydia repositories, there is a package for VIM and there is a custom 'open source' implementation of Java called 'Classpath' but I have no experience of either - I'd imagine both solutions will be cumbersome to work with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are packages on Cydia. There are programmers text editors' like Vim. There's an SDK with GCC, python, ruby etc.

I'd rather write code on punchcards than on a phone or tablet.

Comment: the tools don't install on the iPAD (yet)

Answer (score 0):

There's the "iPhone open toolchain", available on Cydia and elsewhere. There is a video here:

http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/e/943

I believe it hasn't been updated recently. This was how people made Apps before the SDK become widely available.